# SQL - Get rows with ID's that are between 5 and 10..

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL, and need to get the rows that have ID's greater/equal to 5 and less than/equal to 10. Is there SQL that can handle this, or should I use PHP?

Comment: Don't forget to mark this question as answered if you found out what ou need :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats the cool thing about SQL. Its syntax is close to our language. You see I pretty much typed exactly what you asked for.

```
Select * From youTable
Where Id >= 5 AND Id <= 10
```

Also in `T-SQL` the BETWEEN operator would include Both 5 and 10 and do the exact same thing as the previous example. From there it's your choice.

```
Select * From yourTable
Where Id BETWEEN 5 AND 10
```

Comment: Didn't think it was that easy :P

Comment: Yes Sql is easy to use once you get the basic.

Comment: BETWEEN is inclusive by the ANSI standard. It should be inclusive in all databases.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest would be to use [BETWEEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx)

```
SELECT * FROM theTable
WHERE Id BETWEEN 5 AND 10
```

Comment: @mdance Note that depending on the database this may or may not include 5 and 10.  So you may need to change the numbers in the query to 4 and 11.

Comment: My apologies.  TSQL `BETWEEN` is inclusive.

Comment: Why use between why you can simply use <= And >= ?

Comment: Because thats what `BETWEEN` is for.

Comment: I forgot that it was inclusive. So if you had to change the values for the BETWEEN to work it would not have been the best solution. In the case where it is inclusive it's the best option

Comment: MySql `BETWEEN` is inclusive as well.

Comment: BETWEEN is inclusive by the ANSI standard.  It should be inclusive in all databases.

Answer (score 2):

You can use greater than or less than in your `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourTable
WHERE Id >= 5 AND ID <= 10
```